# AsyncTask does not seem to work really async

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I am calling an AsyncTask to stop an previously started service.
But the ProgressDialog does not rotate while the Asyctask is running.
So I think that there is something wrong and I could get problems with an ANR error.

Any ideas?

```
new asyncTaskZieladresse().execute();

public class asyncTaskZieladresse extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
    int progress;
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final Spinner Fahrerauswahl = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        final Spinner Fahrzeugauswahl = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        final Spinner Nutzungsartauswahl = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        Cursor mcursor = (Cursor) Fahrerauswahl.getSelectedItem();
        Fahrer = mcursor.getString(mcursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name"));
        FahrerID = mcursor.getString(mcursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
        mcursor.close();
        Cursor mcursor1 = (Cursor) Fahrzeugauswahl.getSelectedItem();
        Kennzeichen = mcursor1.getString(mcursor1.getColumnIndexOrThrow("fahrzeug_kennzeichen"));
        KennzeichenID = mcursor1.getString(mcursor1.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
        mcursor1.close();
        Cursor mcursor2 = (Cursor) Nutzungsartauswahl.getSelectedItem();
        Nutzungsart = mcursor2.getString(mcursor2.getColumnIndexOrThrow("nutzungsart"));
        NutzungsartID = mcursor2.getString(mcursor2.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
        mcursor2.close();
        VariablenUebergebenGpsFahrt();
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Main.this, "GPS", "Ziel-Standort wird ermittelt...");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    } 
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        stopService(new Intent(Main.this, GPSService.class));
        return null;
    }
```

}

Comment: Since you are not doing anything in the background, what is the point of having an `AsyncTask`? It's like forking a thread with an empty `run()` method.

Comment: I have the problem that it seems to take a lot of time sometimes until the next activity is called. What I am doing is to stop a service (in the services onDestroy() are some values written to sharedprefs, so I can read the collected values from the service after the service is stopped in another activity), then get the selected values from the spinners, hand over the spinner values via intent.putextra and finally call the new activity via startActivity(intent). For me it seems that the stopService took a lot of time, so I was trying to stop it in the AsyncTask. Are I am wrong?

Comment: `stopService()` should take well under a millisecond. It does not do anything directly -- the actual stopping of the service happens asynchronously.

Comment: But I think not the things that I am doing in the onDestroy() method of the service. That may take a bit longer.

Comment: Then you problem lies **inside the service**, not in the `stopService()` call.

Comment: That might be. Thats the reason why I have tried to stop the service with the AsyncTask. The service itself runs already in the background and not in the UI-thread. I try to stop the service in an Asynctask. So if the stopping of the service took a long of time, why is the app hanging? The service and the command that waits for the return of the stopped service (the AsyncTask) are not running in the UI-thread. I have a real understanding problem with that. Sorry :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Thats the reason why I have tried to stop the service with the AsyncTask.

This will not help, as I have tried to explain in the comments to your question. If `onDestroy()` is taking too long, you need to do that work sooner and in a background thread. Putting the `stopService()` call in a background thread is completely pointless.

> The service itself runs already in the background and not in the UI-thread.

No, it is not.

`onDestroy()` is called on the main application thread. **Always**.

Your service might *also* have a background thread of its own for other work, but the lifecycle methods (`onCreate()`, `onStartCommand()`, `onBind()`, and `onDestroy()`) are always called on the main application thread.

> So if the stopping of the service took a long of time, why is the app hanging?

Because you are doing too much work in `onDestroy()`.

> The service and the command that waits for the return of the stopped service are not running in the UI-thread.

`onDestroy()` is called on the main application thread (a.k.a., "UI-thread").

---

**UPDATE** based on first comment:

> When I call onDestroy() inside the service

*You* never call `onDestroy()`. Android calls `onDestroy()`. You are not Android.

> the onDestroy() is not called inside the service for the service itself, rather in the Main thread?

You seem to think that a service is a thread. It is not. You can tell this by reading [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) ("Note that services, like other application objects, run in the main thread of their hosting process. "). Please read the documentation.

Comment: OK, just to get sure I understand it correctly. When I call onDestroy() inside the service (not in the Main), the onDestroy() is not called inside the service for the service itself, rather in the Main thread? In my opinion the service has a onDestroy() for the service itself. Regardless of the activity. If so, how can I get the stop command in the service to do my work before the onDestroy() of the service is called? At the Moment the calling of the onDestroy() in the service is the only way to get know that my service is stopped by the user. I need do write some sharedprefs on stopp service.

Answer (score 1):

It hard to understand why the ANR, but seems that lot of stuff you exec in the `onPostExecute()` could be moved on the `doInBackground()`. Android developers suggest to execute sql lite operation (Content Provider) and every heavyweight operation in a asyn way.

Answer (score 1):

All code in onPostExecute will be executed on the UI thread, only the code in doInBackground will be done in the background...